# tmux window last line to statusbar

Tags: tmux, redirection, window, statusbar

I am running an update-script within tmux, and just to see that the progress is ticking on I would like to see the output from the last line within tmux statusbar.

My idea is to use something that trigger the find function and then pipe it with `trim -1` 
Of course I know that I could pipe the output to a file and then use that output.
The problem is just that the process is already started, and is supposed continue for a few weeks until it's done.

Another Idea I just got. Is it possible to have one window as a part of the statusbar?
If so, then instead of use the actual window I would prefer to clone the original-window,in case I mess things up and accidental destroy it, the cloned window will not be affected.

---

Edit:

I see now that I not should need to use trim -1, the last line should always be the one that show up?

Comment: You might want to look at [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline), which besides doing some fun/useful things for the statusline, can have modules scripted for it.

Comment: do you use xterm? *edit* actually nevermind, I see you want it to be there no matter what window you are viewing. Then if this is a slow process that takes a week, why do you need this to be in your statusline taking up space? You could just as easily move over to that window for a quick look.

Comment: Sorry for late replay @scicalculator . Sometimes the database can be errored, so I would like incoorparate that status line in other windows or within a status-bar in my os (No problem, I use fvwm so I know that part) without the need of manually switching to that cónnection more than give my uname/passwd for  ssh.